# Is it possible to display a string over multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

I have a string that is x (lets say 10,000 for argument sake) char long. I then get to display that string within a `<div>`. So far I can display the whole string in one div, which works fine.

So Assuming i have the following:

**String** - "This string is 10000 characters long"

**divs** - [ div1 ] [ div2 ] [ div3 ]

I want to split the string up and display it over multiple `<div>` elements based on the width/height of the `<div>`.

**result** - [This string ] [is 10000 ] [characters long]

So far I can break up the string into substrings and display part of the string using a `maxCharPerDiv` variable

my JS

```
  var contents; //this is my endless string
  var content;
  var maxCharPerDiv = 1000;
  var currentDiv = "";
  var divsArray = [];

  function contentBreak(str, len) {
    if (str.length < len) {
      return divsArray.push(str);
    } else {
      divsArray.push(str.substring(0, len));
    }
    contentBreak(str.substring(len), len);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    content = contents[i].content;
    contentBreak(content, maxCharPerDiv);
  }

  for (var k = 0; k < divsArray.length; k++) {
    console.log(divsArray[k] + "\n");
  }
```

css

```
div {
  width: 380px;
  height: 582px;
  background: white;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

The above works and returns the substrings in the terminal, but I only get 1 appear on my div, as the rest overflow beyond the set height/width.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to achieve such a display
2. Is it possible to do so based on the width/height of a div?

Greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: _Is it possible to do so based on the width/height of a div?_ Definitely no, unless you have monospace font (and even in this case such things as word wrapping can break the logic).

Comment: I have no idea why are you trying to do that, but if it's just for displaying purposes, you might want to check out CSS multi-column layouts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts

Comment: @hindmost oh...I see. Here I was hoping it was lol! Thanks for letting me know, I'll have to find a way to break the string into separate element and put them back up into their respective divs, maybe? Or try the `CSS multi-column` layout suggested by @helb. And it's just for display purposes. I've got 2 separate divs (might use more) and only one string. And thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a reason on it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div class then add css code to change the div's z-index

e.g.

Your css:

```
#always-on-top {z-index: 9999999;}
```

Should do the trick ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though doing this only sets the stack order of my divs, as mentioned on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_z-index&preval=2). This doesn't allow my string to be displayed on multiple divs :(